# Desired capabilities for iOS - appium desktop

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium

I'm facing an error while trying to test an iphone app with appium desktop. The error image is attached:

[image]

Comment: The error message states what you should do in this situation. Did you try that?

Comment: New to MAC - No Idea, What command to run and where to run!

Comment: Open the Terminal.app and run `sudo xcodebuild -license`

Comment: And what does this have to do with java?

Comment: @pckill - I ran the command n agreed the terms n conditions, but still facing the same error!